# Why @Async annotation of spring is creating the bean twice?

Tags: spring

I am trying to use @Async of Spring. However I am noticing the constructor of the bean where @Async is defined is getting invoked twice.

```
public class TestAsyncAnnotation {

    public TestAsyncAnnotation() {
        System.out.println("-----------con----------");
    }
    @Async
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("From show method");
    }
}
```

configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <task:annotation-driven/>
    <bean name="testAsync" class="com.deva.mvc.testassync.TestAsyncAnnotation" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you share with us the class definition of this bean?

Comment: I have edited the post with the code.

Comment: If that the only Spring configuration file you have?

Comment: Yes. This is the only spring configuration file.